# CSS Height Error

Tags: css, height

I am working with Bootstrap.

The problem I have is that the height of my div are smaller than the space the elements inside the div take up.

My question is how to set the height of my about class so that it will be long enough to include all the elements currently in the div and change as I want to add new elements.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="about container-fluid"><a name="about"></a>
  <div class="col-md-7 border">
    <div class="row">
      <p>My name is Stefan. I am a budding web developer/designer who likes to learn new things. Things I am somewhat compentent in:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>HTML/CSS</li>
        <li>Bootstrap</li>
        <li>jQuery</li>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 border">
    <h2>Coder</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS.

I have my about height set to 20px so you know that it is there. Deleting that line just collapses it altogether.

```
body {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  font-size:26px;
  height:100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}

.navbar {
  background-color:#008e76;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom:0px;
}

.about {
  border:1px solid green;
  margin-top:75px;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
  height:20px;
}

p {
  padding:5px;
}

.portfolio {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:200px;
}

.contact {
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:200px;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Here is my CodePen.
http://codepen.io/stefankenyon/pen/ZOKjxV
Thanks

Comment: You may wish tor review Bootstraps Grid outline, you are not using `.row` correctly in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the fixed height `height: 20px;` from the div:

```
.about {
  border:1px solid green;
  margin-top:75px;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
  height:20px;
}
```

Change to:

```
.about {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 75px;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0axLajmL/)

Comment: The doesn't work. I only set it to 20px so you guys could see it was there. If I set it to nothing it just collapses altogether.

Comment: @pb4759jh68 sorry if I didnt understand isnt this what you wanted? [https://jsfiddle.net/0axLajmL/](https://jsfiddle.net/0axLajmL/)